# Kadelmia lookup operation: how are conflicting values resolved?

Tags: dht, kademlia

The idea behind the lookup protocol is to find the k closest neighbors to the key and check if any of them has the value corresponding to the queried key. Paper: http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.824/2014/papers/kademlia.pdf

My question is, could a conflict of values arise in this situation? For example, one neighbor says the value is `x` and another neighbor says the value is `y`. How are such cases resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The kademlia algorithm only describes the abstract routing and lookup procedures.

Management of values is application-specific and not really part of the algorithm itself. So concrete implementations will handle this differently. They might use timestamps, signatures or return a list of values instead of a single value and let higher application layers resolve inconsistencies.